# Deleted by uss?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've [spotted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158667/how-does-web-development-work-with-python-and-what-is-django-exactly-in-simple) which was deleted two days ago by `uss`. Normally, a "deleted by" username is linked to the user(s) in question.

I know that usernames which don't link are deleted accounts - but I've never seen someone with sufficient permissions to delete a question unilaterally lose their account.

Is this in error or have I just chanced across a mod who has had their account removed in the last 2 days?

Comment: *but I've never seen someone with sufficient permissions to delete a question lose their account*. I have. Usually they requested the full 'delete my account' option themselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added "unilaterally" (= mod?) But fair enough

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The user "uss" was the original owner of the question, before an account merge took place. Delete votes are not transferred to the new account. So the unilateral delete vote was from the post owner, not a moderator.

Comment: Delete votes are not merged? And now I just wonder how would it affect a question ban.

Comment: @Mołot I don't believe *who* deleted something affects the question ban at all.

Comment: Not quite that the *votes* aren't transferred, more that the relevant history entries aren't updated when they are. Retrieving the votes and looking up users is kinda expensive to perform on render, so it generally isn't done that way.